# Unix - sed command to replace only first string seperated by | in a file

Tags: linux, unix, sed, replace

I need help in replacing the first  string and only first string in n lines in a file.

The format is as follows:

```
Str1|str2|str3|str4|str5||
```

This is the format of the file and i need to replace only str1 in all the lines and keep the rest as it is.

I tried

```
sed -i “s#.*|||||#Test|||||#g” filename.txt
```

This replaces the first text with ‘Test‘ which Is fine but replaces the rest of the texts with |||||

Any help?

Comment: Don't use curly quotes in shell commands.

Comment: please add some more sample lines and complete expected output for that sample, is it `str1` on all the lines or something different?

Answer (score 0):

Just match everything that isn't `|` starting from the beginning of the line.

```
sed -i 's#^[^|]*#Test#' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F\| -v OFS=\| '$1="test";1' filename
```

Input file:

```
Str1|str2|str3|str4|str5||
```

Produces:

```
test|str2|str3|str4|str5||
```

Note: this writes to standard output.  If you want to do an in-place edit and are using a sufficiently recently version of GNU awk, there is a `-i` option, but otherwise just write to a temporary file and rename it:

```
filename=my_input_file
tmp_file=my_tmp_file
awk -F\| -v OFS=\| '$1="test";1' $filename > $tmp_file && mv $tmp_file $filename
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar...this was great...work like charm...can you explain the whole command to me..like you said match everything that isn’t | how did you achieve that. If i had to do it for a specific line or starting from second line how could I achieve it.

Comment: @user1969295 Your comment relates to a different answer from the one which it is attached to.